# Root CA certificate invalid on Mac

Tags: catalina, keychain, certificate

I have a root certificate authority file that works on Windows computers, but it is not accepted on Macs since macOS Catalina.

The file was imported into Keychain and marked as trusted in its settings.

However, I am getting this error across all web browsers when trying to browse websites on the Internet. Only pages directly on local LAN are accessible.

`NET::ERR_CERT_INVALID`

It looks like Mac does not like something about the file, how do I find the specific cause?

Comment: I can point you to this link - https://support.apple.com/HT210176 - but it's well above my paygrade to turn it into an answer ;)

Comment: I'm not a Windows expert, but I would say the 825 days maximum validity period is the cause. My certificate has validity set to over 1000 days, fixing it should do the trick. For other requirements I can't tell the difference to Windows...